# Show column in EditForm based on value selected in ComboBoxColumn - ASPXGridView DevExpress

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, devexpress

In ASPxGridView I have GridViewDataComboBoxColumn where in EditForm I choose value. Then I want based on this value show GridViewDataSpinEditColumn or GridViewDataDropDownEditColumn with different VisibleIndex.
In GridViewDataComboBoxColumn I use:

```
<ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="Func"></ClientSideEvents>
```

where Func is:

```
function Func(s, e) {
    var t = s.GetSelectedItem().value;
    table.PerformCallback(t); 
}
```

in my gridview i have: OnCustomCallback="table_SelectedIndexChanged" which looked like:

```
protected void table_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,
ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
{
   SelectedIndexChanged = Convert.ToInt32(e.Parameters);
   if (SelectedIndexChanged == 2)
   {
      ((GridViewDataSpinEditColumn)table.Columns[5]).EditFormSettings.Visible = DefaultBoolean.True;
      ((GridViewDataDropDownEditColumn)table.Columns[6]).EditFormSettings.Visible = DefaultBoolean.False;
   }
   if (SelectedIndexChanged == 3)
   {
      ((GridViewDataSpinEditColumn)table.Columns[5]).EditFormSettings.Visible = DefaultBoolean.False;
      ((GridViewDataDropDownEditColumn)table.Columns[6]).EditFormSettings.Visible = DefaultBoolean.True;
    }
      TableBind();
}

protected void TableBind()
{
   IDataAccess dataAccess = DataAccessProvider.CentralDataAccess;
   this.source.ConnectionString = dataAccess.ConnectionStringToBase;
   this.source.SelectCommand = "dbo.SUB";

   this.table.DataSource = this.source;
   this.table.DataBind();
}
```

And now when I add a new row columns 5 and 6 don't apear (what is expected) but when I choose one of value from my GridViewDataComboBoxColumn EditForm is just reloading and column 5 or 6 don't apear(EditFormSettings.Visible changes in debugging mode).
What should I do to column 5 or 6 apear in EditForm after I select value?
Thank in advance.